# Nginx upstream retry based on response

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

Not all API operations are retriable, so backend send a header retriable = true if the operations can be retried.

How can I say Nginx: retry if the upstream response contains the retriable header?

```
upstream mash {
    ip_hash;
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    server 192.168.0.11:8081;
}

server {

    location / {
        if ($request_method = POST ) {
          proxy_next_upstream error;
        }

        if ($request_method = PUT ) {
          proxy_next_upstream error;
        }

        proxy_pass http://mash/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;        
    }
}
```

The logic I want to implement is the following:

```
if(response.hasHeader('Retriable') {
   do_retry
} else{
   return_backend_response;
}
```

Comment: I would say it's a bad idea, but it's definitely up to you. In case you wonder, HTTP spec has status code `429` and `Retry-After` header (it's applicable also to `503`)

Comment: Can you use PUT for retriable request and POST for requests that shouldn't be retried?

Comment: Have you thought about writing a custom nginx module to do it?

Answer (score -1):

## The Retrier Service

Create a second upstream `retrier` with a very simple web server running that forwards all requests back to nginx on a special port. Then nginx will forward the requests to the `mash` upstream. When the response comes back to nginx, the response will get sent to `retrier` and the logic for retrying can be executed there.